# How do I restructure this Component to create an Object outside of Render to avoid rerendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Music Player getting passed in the link to a song from my Redux State. I want to create the song, and be able to pause it, but the way I have it currently set up is that each rerendering is creating a new Audio Object. **I only want to rerender the creation of the object when the currentSong in my redux state is updating**. How do I refactor the following?

```
 class MusicPlayer extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
      super()

      this.currentSong = '';
  }
  componentWillUpdate(){
      this.currentSong.pause();
  }
  render(){
      let music = this.props.music;
      let isPlaying = music.isPlaying;

      this.currentSong = new Audio(music.songs[music.currentSong]);

      if(isPlaying){
          this.currentSong.play();
      }
      else{
          this.currentSong.pause();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shouldComponentUpdate` for that:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
  // Re-render only when currentSong changes 
  return nextProps.music.currentSong !== this.props.music.currentSong;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats the method I'm looking for. The problem is that I have the above MusicPlayer component passing in other data such as the duration of the song to a child component which doesnt work when I don't rerender the whole thing. Should I just make currentSong into its own component?